# How to amazon s3 update file in bucket to public access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just try to create amazon s3 for static page with this URL
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

And I had create 2 buckets as example.com and www.example.com
And I had put a index.html to example.com
then update the permission of the bucket policy as below

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I had deploy to my host which created in Amazon, but it is still in 403 forbidden as 
Code: AccessDenied
Message: Access Denied

Then I found that index.html in example.com is not public.
And no matter I click the file as "Make public"
and set the public access in permission tab to let everyone to update "read object" in "Access to the object"
It cannot be able to update to public.

any procedure I miss?

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent change in S3 called "Block Public Access" which adds an additional layer of security to prevent people from accidentally exposing content.

In the S3 console for you bucket, go into the **Permissions** tab and edit the **Public access settings**.

If you have added a Bucket Policy, then you should **turn off** the options under "**Manage public bucket policies for this bucket**".